# Compress and Minify registered files and assets in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

How can I compress and minify the files that I have registered using `registerJsFile()` and `registerJs` in view . I have read about 'asset' command but it can be used only for assets not for registered files .

Basically I want to  know how can I compress script that is written on view like in script tag

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
})
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure if it works for your case or not. But found this one http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/escriptboost/

Comment: @RafayZiaMir this is for yii1 I am using yii2

Comment: I know a whole load of time has passed since you asked this but for others searching S.O. there is an extension [here](https://github.com/rmrevin/yii2-minify-view) that will do some compression on the fly but perhaps you should also check-out the asset bundle compression built into yii2: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html